# form submit button as field

Tags: html, forms, button, submit

I am trying to create a form but the buttons Submit and Reset do not display as buttons; instead they show up as fields with the words Submit and Reset in quotes with in the fields. I've searched around and couldn't find an answer for this. I'm very new to forms and PHP so please speak for beginners.

Also in case it is relevant please know that I am designing this to function from my desktop (though I have installed PHP) and that the goal is to have the form post to files, not to a MySQL database.

Here is my code:

```
<form method=”post” action=”">

<table width=”400? border=”0? align=”center” cellpadding=”2? cellspacing=”2?>
<tr>
<td>Username: </td>
<td><input type=”text” name=”username”></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Passwd: </td>
<td><input type=”password” name=”passwd”></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type=”submit” value=”Submit”>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type=”reset” name=”reset” value=”Reset”>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here it is in action: http://masterysoftware.net/The%20OPP/index.html

Comment: PHP is not relevant to this question. PHP is server side, page layout is just dependent on HTML and other client-side technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your quotes. You have question marks where there should be quotes and some weird quotes. I'm guessing part of the problem with the question marks stems from your PHP code which there doesn't seem to be any of.

Try:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
<td>Username: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Passwd: </td>
<td><input type="password" name="passwd"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit">&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: HTML uses straight quotes vs the angled quotes that Microsoft Word-like programs change straight quotes to to conform to writing style vs coding rules